# how to include webpack in in-browser Babel?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, rollup

I am newbie to React.js. For learning purpose just I created the login page which you can find [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xdGjBO).

In my local project also, I used the CDN for babel and react, like below.

```
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@latest/dist/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@latest/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
```

I want to use [one of the form validation plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-form-validate)  into this example. But when I tried to include this (as per the document)

```
import ValidateableForm from 'react-form-validate';
```

I am getting the following error.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

I went through few posts and they said that I have to use webpack or Rollup or Browsify .I am not sure how to include this in to my current local project setup. Since I am not using npm (in learing I dont want to use npm)

1. I dont know how to include that plugin into my project
2. If it is already coming with external site , I cant able to figure
   it out what is the issue.

Please help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: `require` or `import` is resolved by a `transpiler` and the transpiled js gets bundled it into the final js that is rendered to the browser. These are included in`ES6` and not yet implemented in browser.  So if you need to use the particular npm module in question, you can clone and compile it and use the compiled js into your code or if the library provides one you can use them.

Comment: @Panther the whole point is to run the transpiling in the browser, so a person can learn without the overhead

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but at least currently, this is completely possible with conventional script tags.  [This article is very helpful for understanding development setup alternatives for React](https://reactpaths.com/react-myths-or-facts-7d82aef51b01)

In that article it details bringing in React, React-Dom, and Babel via script tags for development, like this (I'm linking to npm downloaded packages, but that isn't necessary):

```
<script src="/node_modules/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="/node_modules/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="/node_modules/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
```

In my case, I needed to bring in the react-notification-system plugin:

```
<script src="/node_modules/react-notification-system/dist/react-notification-system.min.js"></script>
```

(Note the use of the compiled 'dist' version)

Once that was included I was able use it like this:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.notificationSystem = new ReactNotificationSystem();
    }

    addNotification = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const notification = this.notificationSystem.current;
        notification.addNotification({
            message: 'Notification message',
            level: 'success'
        });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.addNotification}>Add notification</button>
                <ReactNotificationSystem ref={this.notificationSystem} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I had to look in the plugin's code to know that the name: ReactNotificationSystem would be available, much of the plugin documentation that you find is not written with this type of dev setup in mind, but it does work.

Comment: That article is brilliant! Thanks so much for the link and your summary here!